# AngularJS: Hide or show object depending on key value of a json array

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new in angular, and I have this 2 issues:
 
I received json data and I want to display different text in my view which depends on the key of my json. 
Example: If the key is `rcs`, `hello this is rcs` will be displayed in my view or if the key is `bank`, `hello this is my bank` will be displayed in my view.

And the second issue: I want to display my object only if "visible" == "true".

So I tried to create an object which has the same key as my json data (screenshot) and have the value I want to display. After that I don't know how to manage this. And even less to display my object if the key "visible" == "true".

Right now, I only succeed to display the key of my json data.

[image: This is my json]

And here is the view :

```
<ion-view view-title="Liste des mentions">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="item item-divider">
      <button class="ion-ios-minus-outline" type="button" name="button"></button>
      <button style="float:right;"class="ion-arrow-move"type="button" name="button" ng-click="moovelement()"></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="list" ng-repeat="(key,value) in mention">

        <li class="item" ng-style="displaymentions">{{key}}

        </li>

    </ul>
    <button class="ion-ios-plus-outline" type="button" name="button" ng-click="addmention()">Ajouter des mentions</button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and the controller :

```
.controller('MentionsCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams','$state','sendtoken',
 function($scope, $stateParams, $state,sendtoken) {



  sendtoken.send(sessionStorage.getItem('token'))
    .then(function(userdata){

      var mentionstva = userdata.data.mentions.vat.visible;
      sessionStorage.setItem('usermentionstva',mentionstva);

      var mentionsretard = userdata.data.mentions.delay.visible;
      sessionStorage.setItem('usermentionsretard',mentionsretard);


      var mentionsbank = userdata.data.mentions.bank.visible;
      sessionStorage.setItem('usermentionsbank',mentionsbank);

        console.log(mentionsbank);
      var mentionsperso = userdata.data.mentions.free.visible;
      sessionStorage.setItem('usermentionsperso',mentionsperso);


      var mentionscga = userdata.data.mentions.cga.visible;
      sessionStorage.setItem('usermentionscga',mentionscga);

      var mentionsrcs = userdata.data.mentions.rcs.visible;
      sessionStorage.setItem('usermentionsrcs',mentionsrcs);



      $scope.mention = userdata.data.mentions;



      if(userdata.data.mentions.visible == "false"){


        $scope.displaymentions = {"display": "none"};
      }
    console.log($scope.mention);


    });

     $scope.jsontab = {
         "bank": "Coordonnées bancaires",
         "vat": "TVA non applicable",
         "delay": "Retard de paiement",
         "rcs": "Immatriculation RCS",
         "cga": "Centre de gestion agrée",
         "free": "Mention personnelle"
     };



  $scope.retard = function(){
      $state.go('app.retard');
  };
  $scope.immatriculation = function(){
      $state.go('app.immatrcs');
  };
  $scope.addmention = function(){
    $state.go('app.addmentions');
  };



}])
```

Comment: `ng-show="visible"` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an answer but this one I feel is a bit simpler and conforms to the json you already have without requiring you to define anything new in your controller.

```
<ul class="list" ng-repeat="(key,value) in mention" ng-if="mention[key].visible">
     <li class="item" ng-style="displaymentions">Hello this is my {{key}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If i want to display something like "hey" when when the key == mention.rcs and "good evening"  when the key == mention.bank how can i manage that ?

Comment: If you only have those two cases then and a series of ng-if statements would work but the way I would do it is by adding a message attribute to your json for each section. Then you wont even need the key,value.
If you can't modify the incoming json, you can run a for loop over it in the controller to add the message attribute to each section dynamically. Does that make sense or do you need an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your first issue :

```
<ul ng-repeat="mention in mentions"></ul>
  <li ng-if="mention === rcs"> Hello this is rcs </li>
  <li ng-if="mention === bank"> Hello this is Bank </li>
</ul>
```

For your second issue :
Add `ng-if="visible===true"` to your object

or in your controller you can set a `$scope` variable  as default **false** and when you are calling your object, that time make it **true**
Then use it in `ng-if` for true condition.